# Variable declaration in parallel sh -c …

Tags: bash, find, variable, gnu-parallel

I've been trying to process the output of `find` with `parallel`, which in turn invoked a shell (some textual substitutions were needed). I observed some strange behaviour, which I cannot really explain to myself.

In each directory there are a bunch of files, call them `file1.xtc`, `file2.xtc`. Some of them have names such as `file1.part0002.xtc`, etc. If the file passed from `find` had the `*.part000x.*` name, I need to remove the `*.part000x.*` bit, such that the resultant command is comething like

```
command -f file1.part0001.xtc -s file1.tpr
```

I used `find` and `parallel` to that effect but `parallel`'s substitutions (in particular, the `{.}` bit) are not quite sufficient (they remove the `.xtc` extension, leaving the `.part0001` alone), so here's a command I used to check my output:

```
find 1st 2nd 3rd -name '*.xtc' -print0 | parallel -0 sh -c 'name=""; name="{.}"; echo {.} ${name%.*}.tpr'
```

If I use the above command, first declaring `name` and assigning an empty string to it (or anything else for that matter), the result is

```
file1.part0001 file1.tpr
```

as required (those are the names I need to use for my command). If, however, I run this

```
find 1st 2nd 3rd -name '*.xtc' -print0 | parallel -0 sh -c 'name="{.}"; echo {.} ${name%.*}.tpr'
```

the result is:

```
file1.part0001 .tpr
```

or it behaves as if `$name` didn't exist.

So the my questions are:

-what is the reason for this behaviour?

-what would be the preferred way of dealing with it?

The first question is more important here, as the method I used above is a workaround, which, while not pretty, works. It is not the first time I needed to do a textual substitution like that and this behaviour continues to baffle me.

Output of `sh --version`

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
```

output of a newer version of `bash` that I installed and used instead of `sh` in the above command (to the same effect) (`/usr/local/bin/bash --version`)

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.0(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin11.4.2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with bash. In fact, since you're telling `parallel` to run `sh`, you may not even be using `bash`.

The issue is that parallel is not really a drop-in replacement for xargs, as its documentation indicates. Instead, it accumulates its arguments into a single string (with spaces between them) and then interprets that as a series of commands. So, in your case, you have:

```
sh -c 'name="{.}"; echo {.} ${name%.*}.tpr'
```

which is interpreted as

```
sh -c 'name="{.}";
echo {.} ${name.*}.tpr
```

Since those are two separate commands, and the first one executes in a subshell (`sh -c`), `$name` is not set in the second one.

Now, you could add pretty well anything to the beginning of the string, such as `true`:

```
sh -c 'true; name="{.}"; echo {.} ${name%.*}.tpr'
```

That will be interpreted as:

```
sh -c 'true'
name="{.}"
echo {.} ${name%.*}.tpr'
```

In this case, the call to `sh` is essentially a throw-away; then `name` is set in the environment maintained by `parallel` and finally `echo` is called with `name` set.

So it would appear that the easiest solution is simply to get rid of the unnecessary call to `sh`:

```
find 1st 2nd 3rd -name '*.xtc' -print0 |
parallel -0 'name={.}; echo {.} "${name%.*}.tpr"'
```

*Note:* Based on a hint given by @StephaneChazelas, I removed the quotes around `{.}` and added them around `${name%.*}.ptr`. parallel does its own quoting of its own substitutions, which interferes in some odd ways with explicit quotes. However, it does not add quoting to shell substitutions, which should be quoted if there is any possibility of the substitution being word-split.

Another option, if you really want to use a subshell for some reason (or a particular subshell), would be to use the `-q` option:

```
find 1st 2nd 3rd -name '*.xtc' -print0 |
parallel -0 -q sh -c 'name="{.}"; echo "{.}" "${name%.*}.tpr"'
```

*Note:* As above, I adjusted the quotes. In this case, the explicit `-q` suppresses the quoting of substitutions, so you have to quote them explicitly. However, this is a textual quotation, which is less accurate than shell quoting; if the substitution includes a double-quote character, that character will not be escaped, so it will close the explicit quotes, breaking the command line and effectively introducing a command injection vulnerability (you'd get other problems for file names contain `$`, `` ` ``, or `\` characters). For this, amongst other reasons, the `-q` option is discouraged.

Comment: That is a very good point. I was indeed expecting it to behave like xargs (where the first, empty declaration of `name` was not necessary). I thought the single quotes should sort things out and the QUOTING section of the manpage was much needed in the end to figure out what was going on (again, contrary to expectations).

Comment: @WojtekRzepala. Yes, unfortunately GNU parallel always calls a shell, and quotes the `{}`, `{.}`... for the shell. For that reason, you should _not_ quote it yourself (so `rici`'s solution is wrong in that regard), and you should avoid backticks for command substitution.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: OK, I think I worked it out. Feel free to critique if I got it wrong.